# Linking: how to force include of .obj / .cpp file or why is it excluded from build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, static-initialization, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have a peculiar case where some [static-initialization](/questions/tagged/static-initialization) code in a .cpp file that is not actually used by the rest of the project seems to be excluded from the build. However, the [static-initialization](/questions/tagged/static-initialization) is important enough. Is there some way - short of making some arbitary function call into the .cpp file - to make sure that this [static-initialization](/questions/tagged/static-initialization) code gets included by the [linker](/questions/tagged/linker) ? (or any pointers to why it may be excluded would be helpfull)

I have tried to expose the struct in a .h file to satisfy the linker - but this was not enough.

Using [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) with [precompiled-headers](/questions/tagged/precompiled-headers) and also [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake).

```
//init.cpp
#include "Pch.h"    
//#pragma init_seg(lib)

struct Init {
  Init(){std::cout << "in Init"<< std::endl ;}
}

Init init;
```

Comment: Is the translation unit in a static library, or in the executable project?

Comment: @Sneftel In a static library